# preserving order of parameters in a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a set of parameters that I use as filters for determining the order of ActiveRecord objects.  For example, I have the following.

```
>> params[:search][:order]             
{"priority"=>"DESC", "last_updated"=>"ASC"}
```

I use `params[:search][:order]` to determine the order in the sql query (don't worry about sql injection, I'm only using these to build the order and are not directly used in the sql).  The problem I'm having is that I need to preserve the ordering.  If I use this in a `link_to`, `last_updated` and `priority` switches which messes up pagination links.  I believe `url_for` uses `to_param` to convert this hash to a url friendly equivalent.

```
>> params[:search][:order].to_param    
"last_updated=ASC&priority=DESC"
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate Array to store the information you need.